# when I make [shp2osm],it show error ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: openstreetmap, libxml2

I want to convert shpfile to osm file
so I will running the 【osm2shp】
but when I make it
the error show:

```
osm.c:(.text+0x82c): undefined reference to `xmlAddChild'
osm.c:(.text+0x869): undefined reference to `xmlAddChild'
osm.c:(.text+0x95c): undefined reference to `xmlAddChild'
osm.o:osm.c:(.text+0x992): more undefined references to `xmlAddChild' follow
osm.o: In function `createXmlDoc':
osm.c:(.text+0xafc): undefined reference to `xmlNewDoc'
osm.c:(.text+0xb0f): undefined reference to `xmlNewNode'
osm.c:(.text+0xb31): undefined reference to `xmlNewProp'
osm.c:(.text+0xb44): undefined reference to `xmlDocSetRootElement'
shp2osm.o: In function `main':
shp2osm.c:(.text+0x40d): undefined reference to `xmlSaveFormatFileEnc'
shp2osm.c:(.text+0x419): undefined reference to `xmlFreeDoc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [shp2osm] Error 1
```

I guess it connect the libxml2,but I don't know how to solve thisproblem

here is detail ：

```
jin@ubuntu:~/Desktop/osmutils-master$ make
gcc -c -Wall `xml2-config --cflags --libs` -lproj transform.c
gcc -c -Wall `xml2-config --cflags --libs` -lproj ruleset.c
gcc -c -Wall `xml2-config --cflags --libs` -lproj osm.c
osm.c: In function ‘tagElement’:
osm.c:80:8: warning: variable ‘key’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  char *key;
        ^
gcc -c -Wall `xml2-config --cflags --libs` -lproj shape.c
gcc -c -Wall `xml2-config --cflags --libs` -lproj shp2osm.c
gcc -Wall `xml2-config --cflags --libs` -lproj -o shp2osm dbfopen.o shpopen.o keyvals.o transform.o ruleset.o osm.o shape.o shp2osm.o
transform.o: In function `sridIsValid':
transform.c:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `pj_init_plus'
transform.c:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `pj_init_plus'
transform.o: In function `transformPoint':
transform.c:(.text+0xe7): undefined reference to `pj_transform'
osm.o: In function `tagElement':
osm.c:(.text+0x285): undefined reference to `xmlNewNode'
osm.c:(.text+0x2b1): undefined reference to `xmlNewProp'
osm.c:(.text+0x2d9): undefined reference to `xmlNewProp'
osm.o: In function `nodeElement':
osm.c:(.text+0x33b): undefined reference to `xmlNewNode'
osm.c:(.text+0x365): undefined reference to `xmlNewProp'
osm.c:(.text+0x393): undefined reference to `xmlNewProp'
osm.c:(.text+0x3c1): undefined reference to `xmlNewProp'
osm.o: In function `nodeRef':
osm.c:(.text+0x3de): undefined reference to `xmlNewNode'
osm.c:(.text+0x408): undefined reference to `xmlNewProp'
osm.o: In function `wayElement':
osm.c:(.text+0x428): undefined reference to `xmlNewNode'
osm.c:(.text+0x452): undefined reference to `xmlNewProp'
osm.o: In function `buildNodes':
osm.c:(.text+0x606): undefined reference to `xmlAddChild'
osm.c:(.text+0x63c): undefined reference to `xmlAddChild'
osm.o: In function `parseLine':
osm.c:(.text+0x82c): undefined reference to `xmlAddChild'
osm.c:(.text+0x869): undefined reference to `xmlAddChild'
osm.c:(.text+0x95c): undefined reference to `xmlAddChild'
osm.o:osm.c:(.text+0x992): more undefined references to `xmlAddChild' follow
osm.o: In function `createXmlDoc':
osm.c:(.text+0xafc): undefined reference to `xmlNewDoc'
osm.c:(.text+0xb0f): undefined reference to `xmlNewNode'
osm.c:(.text+0xb31): undefined reference to `xmlNewProp'
osm.c:(.text+0xb44): undefined reference to `xmlDocSetRootElement'
shp2osm.o: In function `main':
shp2osm.c:(.text+0x40d): undefined reference to `xmlSaveFormatFileEnc'
shp2osm.c:(.text+0x419): undefined reference to `xmlFreeDoc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [shp2osm] Error 1
```

Comment: Seems like you are not properly linking against libxml2. A more detailed build log would be helpful to identify the problem.

Comment: ok I already post the detail，I think my proj4 and libxml2 all not properl linking but I don't how to solve it

Comment: What does `xml2-config --cflags --libs` return?

Comment: -I/usr/local/include/libxml2
-L/usr/local/lib -lxml2 -lz -lm -ldl

Comment: Sounds fine I guess. Sorry, I have no idea what the problem is in your case. Maybe there are two conflicting libxml2 versions installed or something with your linker settings is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a duplicate of [Error while linking libxml2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815791/error-while-linking-libxml2). The order of arguments in the link command is wrong. Libraries must go after object files. You should open an issue, probably [here on GitHub](https://github.com/filbertkm/osmutils).