# gcc dialog library not linking

Tags: dialog, ld

I'm trying to develop a small utility using the dialog library in C (the dialog command in linux).

On fedora linux works fine, but if i try to compile it on debian with the command:

```
gcc -ldialog -lncurses -I/usr/include dialog_test.c
```

I get the following error:

```
vetinari@ankhmorpork:~/Projects/Other/test$ gcc -ldialog -I/usr/include dialog_test.c 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccX6fPYB.o: warning: relocation against `dialog_vars' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccX6fPYB.o: in function `main':
dialog_test.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `init_dialog'
/usr/bin/ld: dialog_test.c:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `dialog_yesno'
/usr/bin/ld: dialog_test.c:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to `dialog_menu'
/usr/bin/ld: dialog_test.c:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to `dialog_vars'
/usr/bin/ld: dialog_test.c:(.text+0xc5): undefined reference to `end_dialog'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The dialog command works fine.

Anyone has any idea why it isn't working on debian?

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417169/why-does-the-library-linker-flag-sometimes-have-to-go-at-the-end-using-gcc

Comment: tried, but i'm just getting similar errors on diferent functions.

Comment: Which are? If you don't tell us the actual errors, it makes it much harder to fix them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61979174/how-to-use-dialog-h-in-a-c-program.
This works for me, on ubuntu 20.04: ```gcc dialog_test.c -ldialog -lncursesw -lm```

Comment: Sorry, was late yesterday and my intetion was to update the question this morning, btw your command is working, i suppose after  i had to change the order of libraries the other problem was the lack of -lm, if you put it as a reply i'll gladly accept it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while linking libxml2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815791/error-while-linking-libxml2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answer for the wiki sake, in case someone comes by here later)

You have to put the libraries you want to link at the end of the gcc command, like this:

```sh
gcc dialog_test.c -ldialog -lncurses
```

The reason is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417169/why-does-the-library-linker-flag-sometimes-have-to-go-at-the-end-using-gcc): The way the linker looks up symbols it has to first see the reference, and then the library prodiving the symbol

Additionally, the dialog library might have other dependencies than `ncurses`. There is explanation how to find out what to include and what to link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61979174/how-to-use-dialog-h-in-a-c-program), in short: `dialog-config` should tell you about it.
In this specific case, what worked for me (ubuntu 20.04) was linking `ncursesw` instead of `ncurses`.

After that, I was left with an

```
undefined reference to `sqrt'
```

linker error, which can be solved by linking the match library using `-lm`.

So, in total, this command works:

```sh
gcc dialog_test.c -ldialog -lncursesw -lm
```